# How to make Rhythmbox stop continuous auto playing songs

Tags: rhythmbox

Every time I choose only one song from Files, Rhythmbox keeps playing the songs I listened to them before.

Anyway to make Rhythmbox stop doing that?

Answer (score 2):

```
rhythmbox --rhythmdb-file '' example.mp3
```

This tells Rhythmbox to temporarily use another library database filename, in this case an empty string so the library is always empty and never saved.

You can use two single quotes (not backticks), or two double quotes, for the empty string. On exiting, it will print this (hopefully) harmless warning: "Couldn't rename  to .tmp: No such file or directory".

You can also use /dev/null as a filename. Then Rhythmbox will print this (hopefully) harmless warning on exit: "Can't save XML: Permission denied".

In both cases, it will not interfere with your default library, which you can get back when you don't specify the 'rhythmdb-file' argument.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Edit menu in the toolbar-**Preferences**-**Music**.

[image]

There uncheck 'Watch my libraries for new files'.

Comment: This makes RB watch the directory for new files to add to the library. The issue is that when RB is invoked to play one file (aka `rhythmbox sillysong.mp3`) it locates it in the library, plays it, then keeps playing through.